# CSS Positioning: wrapping text inside a modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float, css-position

A relatively (I hope) simple question about CSS that I'm clearly just not getting.

I have a modal on my page with the following style definition:

```
.modal
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 86% !important;
    left: 7% !important;
    height: 86% !important;
    top: 3% !important;  
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Inside the modal I would like to have 4 items:
 1) An image on the left hand-side, proportionately resized to the height of the modal
 2) A text box to the right of the image
 3) Another text box, also to the right of the image, and below the first text box
 4) A 'Close' button in the upper-right corner

Here is the mock-up:
[image]

My issue is that when the content of Text 2 goes beyond the end of the modal, instead of the text wrapping, it moves the entire text box below the modal, thus making it effectively invisible.

[image]

I need to allow the text in both Text 1 and Text 2 to wrap, especially in Text 2.

Here is the html code driving this:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <img align="middle" class="modalImg" id="modalImg" />
  <span style="float:left;">
    <h2 id="textBox1"></h2>
    <br/>
    <h3 id="textBox2"></h3>
    <img id="close" src="images/css/close.png" />
</div>
```

And the related css styles:

```
.modalImg
{
    height: 100%; width:auto;
    margin: 0px 25px 0px 0px;
    float: left;
}

.modal #close
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}

h2 {
    color:#384D73;
    font-size:20px;
    margin:20px 0 10px 0;
    clear:both;
}

h3 {
    color:#384D73;
    font-size:18px;
    margin:20px 0 5px 0;
    clear:both;
    line-height: 125%;
}
```

Can anyone help me configure this properly?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just change the height of the modal to `min-height`?

Comment: Also, `span` elements should not contain block level elements like headings.

Comment: Try wrapping the text elements in a div and go from there,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/by8v0tfx/)

```
body {
background:#ccc;
}

* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal {
    position: fixed;
    width: 80%;
    left: 10%;
    height: 80%;
    top: 10%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 10000;
}

.modal-close {
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;
    right:-10px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:#333;
    border-radius:50%;
}

.modal-image {
    position:absolute;
    top:5%;
    bottom:5%;
    left:5%;
    width:45%;
    background: url('http://annerileybooks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Force-Field-LOLCat.jpg') left top no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
}

.modal-content {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:5%;
    bottom:5%;
    right:5%;
    width:45%;
}
```

Comment: This is great!  It's exactly what I was looking for.  Now I'm trying to set the modal image programmatically, but to no avail.  I'm trying this: document.getElementById("modalImg").style.background-image = ...

Comment: I figured it out.  Inside my JavaScript code I simply calling the following: document.getElementById("modalImg").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + record.filePath + "')";

Comment: Ok, one other question.  I just realized that you have set the image in the modal to be a fixed width.  How do I change so that the height of the image is always the height of the modal, and the width is proportional to that?

I tried changing the css def from 'width:45%'; to 'height:100%;width:auto;' but that didn't work...

Comment: I hope you realize that overlapping may happen? So for example image will go below the text? If yes, then instead of image background just use img tag and style it like that `.image {position:absolute; top:10%;bottom:10%;left:10%;width:auto;}`

Comment: Is there a way to limit the overlapping by setting the style properties of the modal-content container so it always aligns next to the end of the image.  In other words, wherever the image ends, display the modal-content div 10 pixels to the right?

Answer (score 0):

make the overflow:scroll for the text2